# Problema con SQL en php

Tags: php, mysql

el codigo especificado abajo es el encargado de setear unos avlores según el dominio desde el que se entra, el problema es que no funciona, los valores no llegan a darse. ¿Alguna solución?
La tabla se llama "nodes"
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
(Los datos de la base de datos han sido censurados)

```
$myhost = "";
$myuser = "";
$mypass = "";
$mydb = "";
$con = mysqli_connect($myhost, $myuser, $mypass, $mydb);
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Sorry, we are unable to connect to the database, try later.";
}
$domain = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$genqueryname = "SELECT * FROM `nodes` WHERE genurl='$domain' AND active='1'";
$resultdomain = mysqli_query($con, $genqueryname) or die(mysqli_error($con));
while ($rowdomain = mysqli_fetch_array($resultdomain)) {
    $gen_id = $rowdomain['id'];
    $gen_name = $rowdomain['name'];
}
```

Comment: ejecutas y asigans a  `$resultdomain` pero pasa a `mysqli_fetch_array()` es `result3`

Comment: intentaste conectarte a la base de datos, porque los campos estan vacios, no esta definida... myhost = "localhost"; myuser = "root"; mypass = "root"; mydb = "data_base";

Comment: es problable que lo haya borrado a proposito para no exponer sus credenciales, se puede inferir eso no es necesario mostrarlos ya que para el fin es importante su codigo para analizar la logica

Comment: me parece que no estas concatenando bien la variale $domain y esas '' del noode deberias eliminarlas

Comment: Si, los datos de la mysql los he ocultado, ya que no son datos locales, si no a una base de datos remota. (El codigo esta en un hosting)

Comment: E arreglado lo que me has dicho y sigue sin funcionar, al quitar las comillas te dice un error "Unknown column 'planetalts.givegen.xyz' in 'where clause'" Un saludo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problema solucionado, las variables $gen_id = $rowdomain['id']; y $gen_name = $rowdomain['name']; no estan bien seteadas. Sustituye por     $gen_id = $rowdomain['id_ass'];
    $gen_name = $rowdomain['genname'];. Un saludo